# Cannot connect my AWS Lambda function to Docker image in ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, lambda, amazon-ecr

I have pushed my docker image into a public repository in the Amazon ECR. But when i try to add the image through my Lambda function, it doesn't acknowledge that there is even a repository i.e, when i click on browse repositories it shows no repository found. When i post my URI for the image, it shows invalid URI.

How can i fix this?

Comment: I have given  "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy" to my execution role yet i cannot fix this

Answer (score 0):

First check if the Lambda function is in the same region as your image in the ECR, if so, check if the lambda function has access to the ECR, give it access with an IAM Role if not

Comment: So the solve was to switch from making the repository private instead of public. I really don't know how was this solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).